# Kubernetes port forward service timed out || Apache Solr

Tags: kubernetes, solr, portforwarding, solr-operator

I have installed the helm for Apache [Solr](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/apache-solr/solr) and following services have been created.
Here is the helm - [link](https://solr.apache.org/charts/solr-0.6.0.tgz)

```
solrcloud-dev-solrcloud-common     ClusterIP   10.232.15.113    <none>        80/TCP              119m
solrcloud-dev-solrcloud-headless   ClusterIP   None             <none>        8983/TCP            119m
```

I would like to forward the service to localhost and I tried as follows:

```
kubectl port-forward service/solrcloud-dev-solrcloud-headless 7000:8983
```

and it shows me:

```
error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

I am wondering if this is because of `None` in the ClusterIP column?

**Note :- Before installing Solr helm, I have installed Solr-Operator and it deployed few pods like below which are running fine**

```
solr-dev-6599654ff5-hbs6v                                  1/1     Running            0          118m
solr-dev-zookeeper-operator-55878f4558-zxbqb               1/1     Running            0          117m
```

Please suggest a workaround for the port forward to work inorder for the solr to be up and running.